# How to delete object if constructor throws an exception?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, constructor, dynamic-memory-allocation

So we have a constructor that can throw an exception depending on the arguments passed to it, but we do not know how to delete the object if this occurs. Important part of the code:

```
try
{
    GameBase *gameptr = GameBase::getGame(argc, argv);
    if (gameptr == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Correct usage: " << argv[PROGRAM_NAME] << " " << "TicTacToe" << std::endl;
        return NO_GAME;
    }
    else
    {
        gameptr->play();
    }
    delete gameptr;
}
catch (error e)
{
    if (e == INVALID_DIMENSION)
    {
        std::cout << "Win condition is larger than the length of the board." << std::endl;
        return e;
    }
}
catch (...)
{
    std::cout << "An exception was caught (probably bad_alloc from new operator)" << std::endl;
    return GENERIC_ERROR;
}
```

In the third line, `GameBase::getGame()` calls the constructor for one of the games derived from `GameBase` and returns a pointer to that game, and these constructors can throw exceptions. The question is, how can we then delete the (partial?) object pointed to by `gameptr` if this occurs? If an exception is thrown, we will exit the scope of `gameptr` because we leave the try block and cannot call `delete gameptr`.

Comment: If the constructor throws, the object isn't constructed.  Not at all, so you don't have to `delete` it.  You only need to worry if you have already allocated resources before the exception is thrown:  the destructor doesn't run.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To assess the exception safety, you need to provide more detail of the construction of the object in `GameBase::getGame`.

The rule is through, that if a constructor throws, the object is not created, hence the destructor is not called. Associated memory allocations are also deallocated (i.e. the memory for the object itself).

The issue then becomes, how was the memory allocated to begin with? If it was with a `new GameBase(...)`, then there is no need to deallocate or delete the resultant pointer - the memory is deallocated by the runtime.

---

For clarity on what happens to the member variables that are already constructed; they are destructed on the exception of the "parent" object. Consider the [sample code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bdfd9e796e4a98e5);

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct M {
    M() { cout << "M ctor" << endl; }
    ~M() { cout << "M dtor" << endl; }
};
struct C {
    M m_;
    C() { cout << "C ctor" << endl; throw exception(); }
    ~C() { cout << "C dtor" << endl; }
};
auto main() -> int {
    try {
        C c;
    }
    catch (exception& e) {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }
}
```

The output is;

```
M ctor
C ctor
M dtor
std::exception
```

---

If the `M m_` member is to be dynamically allocated, favour a `unique_ptr` or a `shared_ptr` over a naked pointer, and allow the smart pointers to manage the object for you; as follows;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;
struct M {
    M() { cout << "M ctor" << endl; }
    ~M() { cout << "M dtor" << endl; }
};
struct C {
    unique_ptr<M> m_;
    C() : m_(new M()) { cout << "C ctor" << endl; throw exception(); }
    ~C() { cout << "C dtor" << endl; }
};
```

The output here mirrors the output above.

Comment: Yes, in getGame(), essentially a "new GameBase()" is returned from a successful call. However, in GameBase(), an exception could be thrown. So to be clear, even if instance variables are initialized before the exception is thrown in the constructor, they are still destroyed (along with the partially created object?) even though the object would have been created on the heap?

Comment: Correct. Any member variables are objects in their own right and once constructed will the destructed if the parent object throws an exception.

Comment: If i recall correctly, that is not always true, when you create multiple objects in one statement, because the allocator and the constructor can be mixed up.

Comment: @hr0m You mean something like `foo(new Bar{}, this_might_throw());`?

Comment: @TartanLlama just see my answer

Comment: @hr0m. If you `new` several objects in a single statement, then yes there can be resultant memory leaks etc. It is generally not advised to do that. If there are several arguments to the constructor that need to be `new`ed, then it is better to create them and assign them to a resource manager (e.g. `std::unique_ptr`, and then "move" them into the object (either move or detach). If the are any exceptions, the RAII mechanism will clean up the resources.

Comment: @Niall so what if in struct C instead of having an M object, it was an M pointer, and m_ = new M(); occurred in the C constructor before throwing the error. Would you have to deallocate this memory yourself? Also, thank you. This has been very helpful.

Comment: Yes, it would not be deallocated. Solve this by making the M pointer a smart pointer such as std::unique_ptr.That will make it automatic.

Comment: @K.Li Yes, if `m_` is a naked pointer, you would. If you use a `unique_ptr`, then no you would not, the `unique_ptr` would take care of that. Hence; `std::unique_ptr<M> m_;` and then use `m_ = new M();` or better still do in the member initialiser list `C() : m_(new M()) {...}`

Answer (score 5):

When you write `Foo* result = new Foo()`, the compiler translates this to the equivalent of this code:

```
void* temp = operator new(sizeof(Foo)); // allocate raw memory
try {
  Foo* temp2 = new (temp) Foo(); // call constructor
  result = temp2;
} catch (...) {
  operator delete(temp); // constructor threw, deallocate memory
  throw;
}
```

So you don't need to worry about the allocated memory if the constructor throws. Note, however, that this does not apply to extra memory allocated within the constructor. Destructors are only called for objects whose constructor finished, so you should get all your allocations into small wrapper objects (smart pointers) immediately.

Comment: And when you say allocations, you mean memory allocated with `new`, correct?

Comment: Actually, I mean any resource allocation whatsoever. Memory allocated with `new`, with `malloc`, with `VirtualAlloc`, file handles, sockets, database connections, everything. It's just a restatement of the RAII principle.

Comment: would result point to nullptr if the constructor throws?

Comment: @MatiasChara `result` would be unaffected. It would have the same value as before the new-expression.

Answer (score -1):

If you throw in a constructor, the object is not constructed and thus, you are responsible for the deletion of allocated resources. This goes even further! Consider this Code

```
int a = function(new A, new A);
```

It is up to the compiler in which ordering is the A allocated AND constructed. You might end up with an memory leak, if your A constructor can throw!

Edit:
Use instead

```
try{
auto first = std::make_unique<A>();
auto second = std::make_unique<A>();
int a = function(*first, *second);
...
```

Comment: So what I'm thinking is that if I allocated resources using "new" in the constructor, I would have to delete them (in a catch block inside the constructor)? What if the instance variables are not allocated using new, but are stack variables?

Comment: Stack variables are ok. Member variables should be ok too. You just have to catch in the constructor and dealocate and then rethrow so the upper code can react too. You could look in the code in fstream, or any Class which uses the RAII principle.

Comment: @K.Li the problem here is that the implementation could choose to allocate memory for both `A`s, then call one of the constructors. If this throws, then the memory for the `A` whose constructor throwed (threw?) will be reclaimed, but the other will not.

Comment: @hr0m A better solution would be to store the intermediate `A`s in `std::unique_ptr`s. That way, if the `second` constructor throws then `first` will be destructed and the memory reclaimed for it.

Comment: How does your code help with a memory leak? If the second one throws, the first is still leaked. Moving the allocations to separate lines is not enough.